# How can I access TapGesture() action/result outside of a struct

Tags: swiftui

I would like to grab the results from "(dream)" and display in another Text and/or View(), (As well as add up with results from other functions) My problem is I cannot work out how to access the results from outside the func.
Note: Sorry if the answer is obvious, Im a newby to Swift (and coding). In saying that, SwiftUI is so much easier to learn :)
Cheers and thanks in advance

```
    let tap = TapGesture()
        .onEnded { _ in
            self.stat += 1
            self.dream -= 3 }
    let tapM = TapGesture()
        .onEnded { _ in
            self.stat -= 1
            self.dream += 3 }
    return HStack {
        Image("clipartBall").resizable()
            .frame(width: 80, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
            .clipShape(Rectangle())
            .shadow(radius: 60)
            .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
            .gesture(tap)
        Text("Against").font(.headline).lineSpacing(20)
        Text("\(stat)")
            .color(Color.green).lineSpacing(20)
        Text("Dream")
        Text("\(dream)")
            .color(Color.green)
        HStack {
        Text("(-)")
            .color(Color.red)
            .gesture(tapM) }
    }.padding()
```

Comment: Can you please post the class that wraps this snippet?

Comment: Hi piebe, There is no class, the code is  a struc which is called by the Content View. The View works in the simulator, adds up and subtracts as required. I wish to be able to grab the Text("\(dream)") value and also view it in another func

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
.....

@State var dream: Int = 0

.....

Text("My state of mind in numerical form: \(self.dream)")
```